# Swift: escaping a closure based on external boolean?

Tags: swift, closures, shortcut, siri

My app need to connect and write to a Bluetooth device by Siri shortcut intents. As soon the completion handler in the IntentHandling class is called, the connection process is terminated.

The Bluetooth handling is covered in a singleton named BTHandler. The write response is confirmed by a delegate function, called by the BTHandler. This is the code of the delegate function and the simplified function for handling the intent:

```
var writeCompleted = false

//delegate function
func writeConfirmed() {
    writeCompleted = true
}


func handle(intent: SwitchIntent, completion: @escaping (SwitchIntentResponse) -> Void) {
    
    BTHandler.shared.responseDelegate = self    

    BTHandler.shared.scan {
    
        BTHandler.shared.centralManager.stopScan()     
        BTHandler.shared.write(btdevice: BTHandler.shared.discoveredDevice, command: .write)   
        
        completion(SwitchIntentResponse(code: .success, userActivity: nil))
    }

}
```

Is there a way call completion only if writeCompleted is true?

Comment: Your question's title and body don't match. "Is there a way call completion only if writeCompleted is true?" Sure, `if writeCompleted { completion(...) }`. "escaping a closure based on external boolean?" That isn't possible, because `@escaping` is an effect that modifies how the caller passes the closure to your function. If it can be escaping, it has a certain set of rules that need to be enforced, and generally more stuff needs to be moved to the heap. It can't know if escaping actually happens or not, so it always needs to act as if it's possible

Comment: How about putting `guard self.writeCompleted else { return }` as a first line of completion handler? Sure it will be called in all cases, but it won't do anything

Answer (score -1):

I've added a timer that is checking if `writeCompleted` is true. This also allow to set a timeout value in case `writeCompleted` is never changing.

Now there's another issue with BT scanning in background, but that is off-topic.

```
func handle(intent: SwitchIntent, completion: @escaping (SwitchIntentResponse) -> Void) {
    
    BTHandler.shared.responseDelegate = self    

    BTHandler.shared.scan {
    
        BTHandler.shared.centralManager.stopScan()     
        BTHandler.shared.write(btdevice: BTHandler.shared.discoveredDevice, command: .write)   
        
        var timeoutCounter = 0.0
            
            Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.2, repeats: true) { timer in
                
                timeoutCounter += timer.timeInterval

                if self.writeCompleted   {
                    timer.invalidate()
                    completion(SwitchIntentResponse(code: .success, userActivity: nil))
                    
                }
                
                if timeoutCounter == 3.0 {
                    timer.invalidate()
                    completion(SwitchIntentResponse(code: .timeout, userActivity: nil))
                }
                
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: Horrible design. Don't ever use timers on anything that is not UI. Don't use timing as a measure of whether something is done. Solve problems, and don't band-aid them with timers / sleeps and so on

Comment: You're absolutely right!  I already replaced my code with an observer that is notifying the IntentHandling class when writeCompleted is true.